# Worklight 6.0 - change Android package name

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

We have an issue with the app signature key, and we might solve it by generating a "new" app - same as the current app, just having a different package name.

We have tested a WL project with Android environment and an Android app, changing the generated Android app package name using

> right click -> Android tools -> Rename Application package

and noticed that it also made the same change in the Worklight Andorid project itself.

We wanted to make sure that this is all we need to do (of course before deploying etc'). Has anyone ever done that?

Comment: I don't see any reference to android package in other worklight files, only in the Android project files, so I believe you did correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generated android project **is** the your-app\android\native project, so it makes sense that by altering the generated Android project, will change it in the same file in the Worklight project.

If this worked well for you, it sounds like everything is OK.

The last time I changed the package name I did it manually, but there too it changed in both locations.